# GNOME MPV not supprting dual audio

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate, 19.10, mpv-media-player

Recently, I installed GNOME MPV player on Ubuntu Mate 19.10. Everything is working fine with that except multiple audio functionality. For dual-audio videos, I'm not able to switch between languages. What can be the problem, Do I need to install some additional drivers

Comment: Default key is the '#' key, this does not work?

Comment: Do you mean "Shift" key + "3" key for "#"?

Comment: Indeed I do, my apologies for not making that clear :)